# Plotting a function in {X(Y),Y} space

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction

The code below generates some data and defines a function f[x,cb]:=NMaximize[expr,x]
that upon being evaluated returns: {function value at max $x$,the function maximizing $x$}.

```
Nobs = 100;
wi = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[2, 2], Nobs];
c = 0.1;
\[Lambda]i = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[2, 4], Nobs];
f[pbar_, cb_] := 
  NMaximize[
   Sum[((((1 - \[Lambda]i[[i]])*Min[wi[[i]], pbar] + \[Lambda]i[[i]]*
             c) - c)*
        Boole[wi[[
            i]] - ((1 - \[Lambda]i[[i]])*
              Min[wi[[i]], pbar] + \[Lambda]i[[i]]*c) - cb >= 
          Max[wi[[i]], 0]] + (pbar - c)*
        Boole[wi[[i]] - pbar >= 
          Max[wi[[i]] - ((1 - \[Lambda]i[[i]])*
               Min[wi[[i]], pbar] + \[Lambda]i[[i]]*c) - cb, 0]]), {i,
       1, Nobs}]*(1/Nobs), pbar ];
```

Evaluating the functions yields:

```
In[197]:= f[x, .1]
Out[197]= {0.146006, {x -> 0.30858}}
```

**I want two plots:**

1. plot f[x,cb][[1]] in the {X,Y} space where  X = cb / (Y - c)
2. plot f[x,cb][[2]] in the {X,Y} space where  X = cb / (Y - c)

**Any suggestions on how I can do this?** Since the function is not continuous I have tried working with DiscretePlot[], but I am having a hard time getting the plotting to work.

PS: the function is rather slow to evaluate--so any comments on how to write the function more efficiently are also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are doing but the plots plat should be simple.
We put all your results in a Table using [`ParallelTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html) to use all available cores in your CPU.

```
data = ParallelTable[
   Block[
    {r = f[x, cb], fmax, xmax},
    fmax = First[r];
    xmax = (x /. Last[r]);
    {cb, xmax, fmax}
    ], {cb, 0, 0.3, 0.3/20}];

TableForm[N@data,  TableHeadings -> {Range[Length[data]], {"cb", "xmax", "fmax"}}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[
 data[[All, {1, 3}]]
 , PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}
 , InterpolationOrder -> 3
 , PlotLabel -> "fmax vs cb"
 , Frame -> True]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[
 data[[All, {1, 2}]]
 , PlotRange -> {-1/2, 2}
 , InterpolationOrder -> 2
 , PlotLabel -> "xmax vs cb"
 , Frame -> True]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]